# iOS: -setFrame stretches the view after CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, core-graphics, transform, frame

I have rotated a UIImageView by calling

`myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(someRadians)
myView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;`

If I call...

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y-100, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height)];
```

... **my view gets stretched**, rather then simply moving upward a bit.

Is this normal behaviour? Im I not supposed to set the frame after rotating a view? Is there a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame):

> **Warning**: If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

In other words, don't use a view's `frame` if it doesn't have the identity transform.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, as *@Scott Berrevoets* suggested, there is no way to use the frame property after making a transformation.

Instead we have to move the view with another transformation. In order to not make the move transformation **override** the rotation, **we can concat the *translation* transformation to the view's existing *rotation* transformation.**

```
CGAffineTransform moveTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(myView.transform, moveTransform);
```